# QML TextField validator does not work on Android

Tags: android, qt, qml

I have written a code below:

```
  TextField {
       id:malzemeolcuinput
       anchors.fill: parent
       validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /\d+/ }
       font.pixelSize: 18
       placeholderText: "Kullanılan..."
       horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
       verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
       }
```

TextField only accepts numbers. On MinGW, when I press alphanumeric like a,b,c, field has no effect. But if I deploy to Android, Textfield accepts any character. What is wrong when I use this code on MinGW?

Comment: Did you use a text prediction? Maybe the validator is not executed in this case.

Comment: Android give different reaction for this case.Normally it is work.When I close keyboart  it works.